# Is there any file I can edit to change the keybindings of Enlightenment 19?

Tags: configuration, keyboard-shortcuts, enlightenment

I would like to edit the keyboard shortcuts used by the Enlightenment window manager and I would like to do so textually by editing some text/XML file. Sort of like how I edit `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml` to change the keybindings used by openbox. Is this possible? I know of the GUI editor of keyboard shortcuts but I would prefer a textual method, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enlightenment's configuration is stored in `".cfg"` files using the Eet library. This is not human-readable, but you can use the `vieet` command to edit a textual representation of a file. For the key bindings, I believe these are stored in `~/.e/e/config/standard/e_bindings.cfg` by default. Vieet also needs a 'section' to edit, put in 'config' here.
The complete command would be `vieet ~/.e/e/config/standard/e_bindings.cfg config`.